# CKEditor: strip element without attributes?

Tags: ckeditor

I've configured *extraAllowedContent* in "config.js" to allow div elements with specific classes, per the [Advanced Content Filtering](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) guide, which is working.

However, I need to strip any div elements that have no attributes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify [`config.disallowedContent`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content) with match function:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    disallowedContent: {
        div: {
            match: function( el ) {
                return CKEDITOR.tools.isEmpty( el.attributes );
            }
        }
    }
} );
```

While it correctly filters out the contents, for some reason (a bug), it also disables the Div plugin and its dialog. Thus I'd rather suggest something like this at the moment:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    on: {
        pluginsLoaded: function( evt ) {
            var editor = evt.editor,
                rules = {
                    elements: {
                        div: function( el ) {
                            if ( CKEDITOR.tools.isEmpty( el.attributes ) ) {
                                // Return false to get rid of an element with children.
                                return false;
                                // The element can also be removed preserving children.
                                // el.replaceWithChildren();
                            }
                        },
                    }
                };

            // Filter what comes out of an editor.
            editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules( rules );
            // Filter what comes into an editor.
            editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules( rules );
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: I'm assuming this code is for the page in which the editor appears. How would I include this in the "config.js" file, and have it apply as global?